# Как редактировать шорткод плагина woof?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

[image: зеленый градиент убрать]Есть шорткод, вставлен через элементор , подключен woof плагин , как я могу зайти через админе панель в редактирвоание кода самого шорткода? или я чего-то недопонял, подскажите

Comment: Смотря что Вы имеете ввиду под "редактирование кода самого шорткода".

Comment: Код шорткода - никак. Он прописан в плагин. Но можно написать свой плагин с нужным шорткодом (аналогом интересуюшего)

Comment: благодарю за отзывчивость. фильтр товаров вставлен через шорткод. мне нужно поменять стили у фильтра

Comment: Для этого не нужно редактировать код самого фильтра, если что. Никто Вам не мешает перестилить фильтры, написав стили в Вашу или в дочернюю тему или добавив их через кастомайзер, например.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.